# How can I "pack" 3 digits into a single number, within a given range?

Tags: java

I am trying to condense 3 numbers, all of which lie within the range of -50 million to +50 million. How can I condense all 3 into a single number and then retrieve the 3 numbers again from un-condensing the single number.

For example if I have:
-3000, 122, 103 will become a single number such as "9484010392"

Uncondensing "9484010392" will return [-3000, 122, 103]

The number 9484010392 is just chosen at random and serves no connection to the numbers in the example, it's just to clarify what I mean by a single condensed number.

etc.

P.S. Writing the program in Java :)

Comment: *How* are you condensing these numbers?  How did you come up with the number 9484010392 from -3000, 122, and 103?  Or is that just a random number, and you're asking for a formula?  If it's the former possibility, you should post what you've tried, what you understand about your attempt, and what you've researched.  If it's the latter, then this is not language-specific, so you should remove the Java tag.  Please edit to clarify.

Comment: It takes 27 bits to store a number in range -50 million to +50 million, so it'll take about 3 * 27 = 81 bits to store 3 such numbers. Unless you intend to use `BigInteger`, Java cannot store numbers of more than 64 bits, so what you're asking is not possible. --- And I wouldn't really use the word "condensed" about the result. The word "combined" would be more accurate.

Comment: Got it, updated the example for more clarification. And alright, that's unfortunate. I would not mind using BigInteger, if necessary.

Comment: What is the use-case for doing this? A BigInteger that you have to pack and unpack every time you use it is going to be more overhead than a simple array of three ints anyway.

Comment: Combining the data to store it somewhere, then retrieve it back to the 3 combined numbers, when necessary. It won't be happening often.

Comment: Why can't you use an array for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "merge" 3 numbers into a single number, where the merged value is small when the 3 inputs are small, including sign, we can interleave the bits of the numbers, putting a separate sign bit last ([LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit)).

E.g. for inputs `[-3000, 122, 103]`, the bit math is:

```java
-3000  ->  sign=1, mag = 3000 = 0b1011_1011_1000  ->  0b1_0111_0111_0001
122  ->  sign=0, mag = 122 = 0b111_1010  ->  0b1111_0100
103  ->  sign=0, mag = 103 = 0b110_0111  ->  0b1100_1110
```

To merge them, we need to inject two 0-bits between the bits, and shift two of the numbers one and two bits to the left, then combine them using bitwise `OR`.

```java
shift=0, 1011101110001  ->  1000001001001000001001001000000000001
shift=1,      11110100  ->                10010010010000010000000
shift=2,      11001110  ->               100100000000100100100000
                       OR:  1000001001001110111011011100110100001 = 69958744481
```

If the result is stored in a 64-bit `long`, that leaves 21 bits for each number, which is 1 sign bit and 20 magnitude bits, so it can handle values up to ±1048576, i.e. about ±1 million.

If you want a range up to ±50 million, the result must be stored in a `BigInteger`.

Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but good luck coding it, if it is.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to require small outputs for small inputs, so a straightforward packing like `(num1 << (2*width)) | (num2 << width) | num3` would be simpler. This exact formula won't work for negative numbers, but the details are easier to get right than interleaving bits.

Comment: @kaya3 The question ends up with a "small" 9484010392 value even though one of the inputs is negative (-3000). Without isolating the sign bit like I'm doing, an small `-1` value would leave the result huge, because `-1` in a 27-bit two's complement is `67108863`, which becomes `1208925819614629174706176` when the bits are separated by two 0-bits, and that is a much larger number, just because the input is `-1`.